Apache Redirect permanent clashing with htaccess
My server is Ubuntu
I have following .htaccess -
    # Disable directory browsing
    Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

     <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>

My .conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>

When I add Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com to the .conf file, I get error "Too many redirects ..."
Why the server is looping while resolving Redirect permanent?
What configuration can I have to get all my traffic to https://www.eperssona.com?
I tried -
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
Expecting all the traffic to go to https://www.example.com
It instead resulted in too many redirects
